# Why Can't I get progressbar.js working in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, electron

I am currently making an application in Javascript and Jquery with node.js and electron that will download it's db files on first run. I want to implement the progressbar.js so that it shows a download bar when the files are downloading.  I am following the setup guide for [progressbar.js](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/) and implemented a javascript download with progress from [ourcodeworld.com](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/228/how-to-download-a-webfile-with-electron-save-it-and-show-download-progress) however, when running my electron app, the download bar does not render at all. How would I get this to work in electron so that the progress bar renders and shows the download progress?

HTML CODE

```
<body>

    <div id="container"></div>

</body>
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
            var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(container, {
                strokeWidth: 4,
                easing: 'easeInOut',
                duration: 1400,
                color: '#FFEA82',
                trailColor: '#eee',
                trailWidth: 1,
                svgStyle: { width: '100%', height: '100%' }
            });
            function progress() {
                bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
            }

            function downloadFile(file_url, targetPath) {
                // Save variable to know progress
                var received_bytes = 0;
                var total_bytes = 0;

                var req = request({
                    method: 'GET',
                    uri: file_url
                });

                var out = fs.createWriteStream(targetPath);
                req.pipe(out);

                req.on('response', function (data) {
                    // Change the total bytes value to get progress later.
                    total_bytes = parseInt(data.headers['content-length']);
                });

            req.on('data', function (chunk) {
                // Update the received bytes
                received_bytes += chunk.length;

                progress();
            });

            req.on('end', function () {
                alert("File succesfully downloaded");
            });
        }
downloadFile("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/butterfly-wallpaper.jpeg", "./varbutterfly-wallpaper.jpeg");
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6a8hm1za/3/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't do anything because there's no build tooling in the fiddle. You should fix it so that it doesn't use `require()`, and move the call to `downloadFile()` into the JS part. Also, please be more specific about 'not working' part. Does it render but not animate, or does it not render at all?

Comment: @hayavuk it does not render at all. I'll make those changes to the fiddle now

Comment: @hayavuk updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lm7kp3ka/2/  Like I said before it doesn't render at all.

Comment: You should learn how to use the developer tools, the JavaScript console at least. Open the developer tools (usually F12 does it), and check the console tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always give the value to the progress with 1.0

```
function progress() {
    bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
}
```

So please change it to

```
function progress(val) {
    bar.animate(val);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
}
```

and then change the update from

```
req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    // Update the received bytes
    received_bytes += chunk.length;
    progress();
});
```

to this

```
req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    // Update the received bytes
    received_bytes += chunk.length;
    progress(received_bytes/total_bytes);
});
```

as you can see you will find out that the progress change for every chunk update and divide it by the `total_bytes` if it is all downloaded then it will be 1.0 else will be the animation you need.

or you can change the progress function to

```
function progress(val) {
    bar.set(val); // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
}
```

for setting the value exactly without animation.

Comment: Happy to help anytime.

Comment: :( sorry I am not that good in fiddle but i think it is messing the reference for the object we are using, it give me `Uncaught ReferenceError: ProgressBar is not defined
    at window.onload ((index):45)
window.onload @ (index):45`

Comment: I just fixed that New Fiddle-https://jsfiddle.net/Lm7kp3ka/6/ now I am getting`ReferenceError: request is not defined
    at downloadFile ((index):88)
    at window.onload ((index):112)` only and when I test in my electron app it doesn't even render. In the fiddle at least I get the empty line

Comment: where is the function `downloadFile` ??

Comment: I am just revisiting this sorry it took me a while to answer the downloadfile function is on line 14 of this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6a8hm1za/4/)